# JAVA Date string without symbols

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm formatting **Date** to **String** without symbols **:,/,-** using **SimpleDateFormat**, but it formats it strangely.

Here's my code :

```
public static String getFormatedDate(Date date, String format) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    return simpleDateFormat.format(date);
}
```

And I call it like this :

```
DateUtil.getFormatedDate(new Date(), "DDMMYYYYHHMMSS")
```

Return of the call is incorrect **2540920170909379** it should look like this **11092017093405** = **11/09/2017 09:34:05**

Comment: Watch the case of those format pattern letters. `d` and `D` doesn’t mean the same. Neither `y` and `Y`, etc.

Comment: Tell us, why are you still sticking to the outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class? Telling from the number of questions on Stack Overflow, this class seems to be causing lots of confusion and trouble. I recommend you throw is´t overboard and instead use [the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It’s much nicer to work with. Its class for formatting is `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: If possible, use standard ISO 8601 formats rather than devising your own.

Comment: `ZonedDateTime.now().format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "ddMMuuuuHHmmss" ) )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following;

```
DateUtil.getFormatedDate(new Date(), "ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
```

See [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for complete format

Comment: Oh my .... Bad mistake, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the wrong output is because you are not using the correct [date-time formatting pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You can use these characters:

- `y` = Year
- `M` = Month in year
- `w` = Week in year
- `W` = Week in month
- `D` = Day in year
- `d` = Day in month
- `F` = Day of week in month
- `E` = Day in week
- `a` = Am/pm marker
- `H` = Hour in day (0-23)
- `k` = Hour in day (1-24)
- `K` = Hour in am/pm (0-11)
- `h` = Hour in am/pm (1-12)
- `m` = Minute in hour
- `s` = Second in minute
- `S` = Millisecond

You may want to use this pattern: `ddMMyyyyHHmmss` for getting "datetime" like output.

Answer (score 1):

Then in place of

```
DateUtil.getFormatedDate(new Date(), "DDMMYYYYHHMMSS")
```

you should provide the correct format

```
DateUtil.getFormatedDate(new Date(), "ddMMyyyyHHmmss")
```

Comment: if that worked for you don't forget to accept it.